# Javascript split a string by specified character only once then ignore rest

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string that is similar to 1-My-Name the number is an ID that I need to split from the text but I still need to display the text also. After splitting I get just 'My' whereas I need My-Text.

```
this.$route.params.topic.split('-');
```

I need it to only split once so I have the ID then no longer split. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match a `-` and then put everything after it into a capture group, then take that capture group:

```js
console.log(
  '1-My-Name'.split(/-(.+)/)[1]
);
```

Also works with `match` instead of `split`:

```js
console.log(
  '1-My-Name'.match(/-(.+)/)[1]
);
```